# Serial.parseInt works for first menu but now in a sub menu

Tags: serial, input, print

I am trying to use the `Serial` object to print some lines giving the users some options to select by entering an int. It works at this main menu. But when the user selects 1 I use `Serial` again to print some lines and collect another int. But in this submenu it prints the line, waits a second and then continues back out to the main menu. Below is my entire sketch:

```
int menu = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //Starting the serial comm
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (menu == 0) {
    //Prints the menu to the serial port
    Serial.println("Select an option:");
    Serial.println("-----------------");
    Serial.println("1) Do Submenu");

    menu = getSerialInt();
  }

    //Used to calibrate the pen height
  if (menu == 1) {
    int calibrating = 1;
    while (calibrating == 1) {          //While loop that will continue until "0" is sent in the serial port
      Serial.println("Enter a pen value: ");
      int penMove = getSerialInt();
      
      Serial.println("You entered: ");
      Serial.println(penMove);
      if (penMove == 0) {
        calibrating = 0;
      }
    }
    menu = 0;   //Sets the menu variable back to 0
  }
}

int getSerialInt() {
  int retInt;
  Serial.flush();

  while (!Serial.available()) {}  //Waits for an input on the serial device
  retInt = Serial.parseInt();       //Takes the Serial input and looks for an integer
  Serial.flush();
  
  return retInt;
}
```

Thanks in advanced for any help trying to debug this.

Answer (score -1):

Based off this thread: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/parseint-clears-serial-available-but-leaves-terminator-in-serial-buffer/515199/8

And some other threads talking about carriage returns, I rewrote `getSerialInt` to call parseInt() twice to trow away the carriage return:

```
int getSerialInt() {
  int retInt;
  Serial.flush();

  while (!Serial.available()) {}  //Waits for an input on the serial device
  retInt = Serial.parseInt();       //Takes the Serial input and looks for an integer
  Serial.parseInt(); // throw away carage return
  Serial.flush();
  
  return retInt;
}
```

There is probably a better way to do this...